# calculate sum of each .col-* with same position on different row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to sum each column with the next column that is in the same position in the next .row. For example:

All columns are created dynamically and have the same class. Can you help me to do it (with jQuery o Javascript)?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sum = 0;

  $('.col-1').each(function(index) {
    sum += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(',', ''));
  });

  $('.total').html(sum);
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1"><input type="number" /></div>
  <div class="col-1"><input type="number" /></div>
  <div class="col-1"><input type="number" /></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1"><input type="number" /></div>
  <div class="col-1"><input type="number" /></div>
  <div class="col-1"><input type="number" /></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1"><input type="number" /></div>
  <div class="col-1"><input type="number" /></div>
  <div class="col-1"><input type="number" /></div>
</div>

<div class="result">
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-1"></div>
</div>

<div class="result">
  <div class="col-1">(( row1 col1(first-child) + row2 col1(first-child) + row3 col1(first-child) = 12 ))</div>
  <div class="col-1">(( row1 col2(second-child) + row2 col2(second-child) + row3 col2(second-child) = 8 ))</div>
  <div class="col-1">(( row1 col3(third-child) + row2 col3(third-child) + row3 col3(third-child) = 6 ))</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet demo above so it shows your problem.

Comment: If you cannot do it with jQuery then do it without jQuery. Some loops would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Plain JavaScript Solution**

Using plain JavaScript you can sum the columns with one (long) line of code.
This solution uses the [nth-child(index)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector to get all the values in a column. The + prefix on innerText [coerces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#number_coercion) the string to a number when doing the sum. See [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Anot()) for the `:not` selector before using.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.result .col-1').forEach((result,index) => 
    document.querySelectorAll(`.row:not(.result) .col-1:nth-child(${index+1})`)
    .forEach(cell => result.innerText = +result.innerText + +cell.innerText)
);
```

**Update**

In a follow up question, OP asks how to dynamically sum inputs in a column. This can be done by modifying the original code to select the inputs and sum their values. We also need to reset the column sum during each update. This is done using [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) that sets the previous sum to zero when the index is zero. The snippet contains additional code for the event handler and validation.

```
  document.querySelectorAll('.result .col-1 input').forEach((result, index) =>
    document.querySelectorAll(`.row:not(.result) .col-1:nth-child(${index+1}) input`)
    .forEach((cell,i) => result.value = +cell.value + (i ? +result.value : 0))
  );
```

**Snippet**

Open and run the snippet to understand how it works.

```js
function update(event) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.result .col-1 input').forEach((result, index) =>
    document.querySelectorAll(`.row:not(.result) .col-1:nth-child(${index+1}) input`)
    .forEach((cell,i) => result.value = +cell.value + (i ? +result.value : 0))
  );
  
  // optional - browser displays message when input invalid
  if (event) event.target.reportValidity(); 
  
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  // update once on page load
  update();

  // update after when there is a change
  document.querySelector('#showsum').addEventListener('change', update);

})


/* original solution 
document.querySelectorAll('.result .col-1').forEach((result, index) =>
  document.querySelectorAll(`.row:not(.result) .col-1:nth-child(${index+1})`)
  .forEach(cell => result.innerText = +result.innerText + +cell.innerText)
);
*/
```

```css
.col-1 {
  min-width: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="showsum" class="container p-2">
  <strong>Column Sum</strong>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 p-1">
      <input type="number" class="form-control text-end" required value="3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 p-1">
      <input type="number" class="form-control text-end" required value="2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 p-1">
      <input type="number" class="form-control text-end" required value="1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 p-1">
      <input type="number" class="form-control text-end" required value="4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 p-1">
      <input type="number" class="form-control text-end" required value="4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 p-1">
      <input type="number" class="form-control text-end" required value="1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 p-1">
      <input type="number" class="form-control text-end" required value="5" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 p-1">
      <input type="number" class="form-control text-end" required value="2" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 p-1">
      <input type="number" class="form-control text-end" required value="4" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row result">
    <div class="col-1 p-1">
      <input type="number" class="form-control text-end text-primary" readonly value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 p-1">
      <input type="number" class="form-control text-end text-primary" readonly value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 p-1">
      <input type="number" class="form-control text-end text-primary" readonly value="0">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: this works well! can this work with `<input type="number" />` inside the div and that it sums as you type? (i updated my question) thanks yogi!

Comment: @blacksun___ - Answer has been updated.  Run the snippet and the sums will change as you change the values of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

First find how many rows there are. If it's constant, then use a constant number instead.

Then just run through each `.row` except for results, and add-up to totals.

Finally show results.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   var totalRows = $('.row').eq(0).find('.col-1').length;
   var totals = {};
   
   $('.row:not(.result)').each(function () {
       for (var i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
           if (totals[i] === undefined) {
               totals[i] = 0;
           }
           
           totals[i] += parseInt($(this).find('.col-1').eq(i).text());
       }
   });
   
   console.table(totals);
   
   $.each(totals, function (index, total) {
       $('.row.result .col-1').eq(index).text(total);
   });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1">3</div>
  <div class="col-1">2</div>
  <div class="col-1">1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1">4</div>
  <div class="col-1">4</div>
  <div class="col-1">1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1">5</div>
  <div class="col-1">2</div>
  <div class="col-1">4</div>
</div>

<div class="row result">
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"Interesting"_ (as in unnecessary) mix of jQuery and non-jQuery stuff.